# iOS 6 and iAds giving too many warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, iad

Here is my iAd code and I'm getting warnings about

```
setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers - deprecated in iOS 6
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 - deprecated in iOS 4.2
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32 - deprecated in iOS 4.2
setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier - deprecated in iOS 6
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32 - deprecated in iOS 4.2
```

How do I fix this so there are no warnings.

```
- (int)getBannerHeight:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        return 32;
    } else {
        return 50;
    }
}

- (int)getBannerHeight
{
    return [self getBannerHeight:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
}

- (void)createAdBannerView
{
    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (classAdBannerView != nil) {
        self->adView = [[classAdBannerView alloc]
                              initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [adView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                                          ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50,
                                                          ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32, nil]];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
            [adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:
             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32];
        } else {
            [adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:
             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
        }
        [adView setFrame:CGRectOffset([adView frame], 0,
                                             -[self getBannerHeight])];
        [adView setDelegate:self];

        [self.view addSubview:adView];        
    }
}

- (void)fixupAdView:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (adView != nil) {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            [adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:
             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32];
        } else {
            [adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:
             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
        }
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fixupViews" context:nil];
        if (bannerIsVisible) {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [adView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
            [adView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect contentViewFrame = _contentView.frame;
            contentViewFrame.origin.y =
            [self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            contentViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height -
            [self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            _contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
        } else {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [adView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.y =
            -[self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            [adView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect contentViewFrame = _contentView.frame;
            contentViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
            contentViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
            _contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using **deprecated** methods/symbols.

Deprecation means the methods/symbols are still here, and will usually still work, but they may be removed on future iOS versions.

The official documentation always list the deprecated methods/symbols, and usually provides the new ones.

So I hate to say this, as an answer, but just **read the doc**.

Warnings about iOS 6 are not too bad, as iOS 6 is pretty new.
But also fix them if you can. What is done is done.

But it seems you are also using methods/symbols that were deprecated on iOS 4.2!
This is actually a concern. iOS 4 support is currently dropping, so your actual code might not work for long.

So read the doc (again), learn about the new methods, and fix your code.

For instance:

```
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 - deprecated in iOS 4.2
```

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), you can read the following:

> ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 Indicates that the banner view is
>   320 points by 50 points in size. This size is used on iPhone for
>   portrait advertisements. **(Deprecated. Use
>   ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait instead.)** Available in iOS 4.0
>   and later. Deprecated in iOS 4.2. Declared in
>   ADBannerView_Deprecated.h.

So instead of `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50`, simply use `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait`.
Same for `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32`. Use `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` instead.

You'll then be safe, and you'll no longer have a warning about this.

Then simply do the same for the other symbols.

**EDIT**

---

As stated on your comment, `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` are also deprecated on iOS 6.

This is related to the deprecation of `setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier` and `setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers`.

Apple recommends not to use that approach anymore, and use the **auto-resizing** capabilities of iOS.

Comment: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait is also deprecated as of iOS 6

Comment: Damn it. It's always something. Know any good places (other than Apple's ambiguous docs to learn about autosizing)