# Game shows iAd on iPad successfully, but not in final build submitted for review. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, iad, adbannerview

## Summary:

I implemented iAd in my game using the Unity built-in AdBannerView functionalities. The game successfully showed the iAd test ad on iPad when it's executed via xcode. However, the submitted game was rejected by Apple reviewers because of this reason:

"We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality."

In the resolution center, I posted some screenshots to prove that my game showed the test ad. They replied with screenshots that showed that ad didn't appear at their end.

## Detail:

The following is the code I wrote to implement iAd:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class iAdManager : MonoBehaviour {

#if UNITY_IPHONE
    private ADBannerView banner = null;

    void Awake () 
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }

    void Start () {
        banner = new ADBannerView (ADBannerView.Type.Banner, 
                                   ADBannerView.Layout.BottomCenter);

        // subscribe functions to Banner events
        ADBannerView.onBannerWasClicked += OnBannerClicked;
        ADBannerView.onBannerWasLoaded  += OnBannerLoaded;
    }

    void OnBannerClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!\n");
    }

    void OnBannerLoaded()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loaded!\n");
        banner.visible = true;
    }
#endif
}
```

I did a 'build and run' on Unity. The build appeared on xcode, with some warnings about depreciations of some banner sizes. The game then showed up on my iPad, with the test iAd being successfully displayed at the bottom.

For the submission process, I loosely followed the official video tutorial. I say 'loosely' because the xcode UI has changed since, so I could only follow adaptively. Briefly speaking, I changed the code signing to iOS distribution, cleaned, archived, validated and submitted it via xcode.

What did I do wrong? Thank you for your help.

(Here's proof of my game successfully show a test iAd when executed on xcode)

[the screenshot showing test iAd](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71529803/BB_iAd_small_cropped.png)

[screenshot of xcode showing warnings](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71529803/mac%20screen.png)

Comment: I think those warnings would be a clue. Could you post them?

Comment: @KarolS, I've added a screenshot of xcode showing the warnings. Please let me know if you need more info, thank you.

Comment: 1. Do the reviewers know where the ads can be seen( if they fail to find them they will reject)? 2. Did you test your code on different devices (they might be testing on another device) 3. Did you read [this article](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/02/11/overcoming-issues-with-ios-app-store-submissions/)?

Comment: This questions may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697330/ios-6-and-iads-giving-too-many-warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223763/adbannercontentsizeidentifier320x50-deprecated-now-what

Comment: @Rudolfwm: the screenshot I sent them showed where the iAd would appear. I only have 1 device, unfortunately. The article you cited is not related to my issue because it stated an exactly opposite scenario.

Comment: @KarolS other unity users submitted their games with the same deprecation warnings, but they don't have issue showing ads. Deprecations just mean 'not recommended', but they are not errors.

Comment: The article could be related to your situation if you are showing ads in parts of your game only. It may very well be that the reviewers at apple never got there. Having said that, I would try to see if I could recreate the Apple reviewers situation. Have you tested on a clean device (ie started allover, all inherent data removed).

Comment: @Rudolfwm: in my game, the iAd is meant to be served on every screen. The Apple reviewers sent me back 3 screenshots (main menu, level selection, main game room) to show that they don't see in any of them.  on my iPad, I was able to see the test iAd in every scene.

Comment: @Rudolfwm: everytime I run the game from xcode, I would uninstall the previous one first. I dunno how else to recreate the Apple reviewers' situation because I don't know how they test, or what device they use.

Comment: Full rejection message from Apple is as follows: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71529803/rejection%20msg.png

Comment: My app has been rejected a second time.

In my 3rd submission, I'll say 'No' to the question 'Does this app use IDFA' posed during the app submission stage.

We've been told that we don't need to modify the DeviceSettings.mm anymore after Unity 4.5.x, when I do a grep -r on the xcode project folder generated by Unity, I STILL see the following. Is this the reason why my app is rejected? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71529803/grep%20screen.png